# Save savedInstanceState in reference leaks memory on screenRotation

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I save the saveInstanceState Bundle to a reference in my fragment like this:

```
 this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
```

in my onCreateView(). The savedInstanceState reference is not static.

When I do it like this it leaks the whole context. However, after removing this line the leak does not occur anymore. The this.savedInstanceState reference is not used anywhere anymore in my code than in this line.

So right now I am really confused how this simple line could cause memory to leak?

Comment: what do you store in savedInstanceState?

Comment: savedInstanceState is the bundle that comes as a parameter with the onCreateView() method and is stored in a reference of type Bundle I called savedInstanceState as well in my fragment

Comment: It's not possible for a `Bundle` to leak an `Activity`, unless it is somehow explicitly stored inside it as a `Parcelable` etc.

Comment: in the outState bundle in onSaveInstanceState() I store a serialized object and then it is restored in onCreateView

Comment: What's in your serialized object a `View` or a `Bitmap`?

Comment: None of both. It's an object that just contains primitive types